# paypal integration in android app in which the app could transfer the payment back to user account

Tags: android

I have implement user to transfer money from its account using paypal merchant id but how can i transfer money to user account i have applied the code

Code :

```
PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(amount), "USD", "Football Payment", PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
//Creating Paypal Payment activity intent
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PaymentActivity.class);
//putting the paypal configuration to the intent
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

//Puting paypal payment to the intent
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);

//Starting the intent activity for result
//the request code will be used on the metho
//onActivityResult
startActivityForResult(intent, Url.PAYPAL_REQUEST_CODE);
```

now i need to transfer the amount to user account on button clicked

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/refund-payments/#integration-steps

Comment: Actually this is the gaming application and the user transfer the payment and the amount is added into the application and now the user play the game and win or loss now the user need to transfer money to his account how it is possible

Comment: For security reasons you will have to send the payment. Users will not be able to send themselves money from your PayPal account.